# Advice on Apache Camel and Quartz in cluster mode to implement different routes to move files

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, apache-camel-cluster-mode

the basic objective my application is to move files from source directory to destination directory.
The application should to be able to handle multi different routes adding or deleting them at runtime.

I'd like to implement a Spring Boot app by using Quartz in *cluster mode* (clustering mode  is in case of having at least two applications up and running) and Apache Camel to have many different connectors's type and apply many routes written in a database table.

Hypothetical approach that I'd like to adopt would be:
define a job Quartz running every x minutes and it should take the set of routes
eg.

```
from("file://sourcefolder1/?delete=true").to("file://destFolder1")
from("file://sourcefolder2/?delete=true").to("file://destFolder2")
```

written in a db table and apply them during the Quartz Job execution.

Do you have any suggestions and advice on this ?